# how to invoke different methods without using if,switch,conditional operator,reflection,while statement in java

Tags: java

I got a problem..I recieve mainly 3 types of inputs from command line arguments in java..say A,B,C.Based on these three inputs I need to invoke respective method (I have 3 methods defined one for each input).

condition is : we should not use if,switch,conditional operator,while statement,reflection

any one please share your thoughts

Comment: Depending on whether you consider methodhandles to fall under reflection, you could also create a sort of 'switch' with that. But if you know the list of methods at compile @Eran's answer is very good.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Map` in order to map the 3 possible inputs to the 3 corresponding methods.

For example, suppose the input is a `String` and the logic to be performed is a method that accepts a `String`:

```
Map<String,Consumer<String>> methods = new LinkedHashMap<>();
methods.put("A",a->methodA(a));
methods.put("B",a->methodB(a));
methods.put("C",a->methodC(a));
```

Now, given input `x`, you invoke the required method with

```
methods.get(x).accept(input);
```

You can use `getOrDefault` instead of `get` if you want to have a default method invoked when the input `x` is not found in the `Map`:

```
methods.getOfDefault(x, a -> System.out.println("cannot process input " + a)).accept(input);
```

Comment: Thanks Eran for the solution.I didnt understand how should I invoke the respective  method..thats the only point I didnt get it..Request you to explain for me

Comment: @javalearner you invoke it with `methods.get(x).accept(input);`. For example, `methods.get("A").accept(input);` with call `methodA(input)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an interface with a common method

```
import java.util.*;

interface A{
    public void run();
}
public class MyClass implements A{

    public static void method1() { System.out.println("method1"); }
    public static void method2() { System.out.println("method2"); } 
    public static void method3() { System.out.println("method3"); }
    public void run(){}
    public static void main(String [] args){
        A method1 = new A() { 
            public void run() { method1(); } 
        };
        A method2 = new A() {
            public void run() { method2(); } 
        };
        A method3 = new A() {
            public void run() { method3(); } 
        };

        Map<String, A> methodMap = new HashMap<String, A>();
        methodMap.put(args[0], method1);
        methodMap.put(args[1], method2);
        methodMap.put(args[2], method3);

        A a = methodMap.get(args[0]);
        a.run();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Monu..Even this is  working..New learning for me..I have small query..in case use enters unknown value which is not present in the map..how should we handle it need to show a message to the user in such scenario

Comment: In this case, you can use if(methodMap.get(userInput) == null){ // give message ; }else{ // fetch method }

Comment: but I should not use it,switch,conditional operator,while statements